# How to import Builder Classes?

Tags: java, javafx

I can't import javafx.scene.shape.RectangleBuilder; There are not such class in my jar file.How can I solve this problem?
For example:

Rectangle rectangle1 = RectangleBuilder.create()
.x(10)
.y(20)
.width(200)
.height(100)
.fill(Color.RED)
.build();

I want to write this code,but JVM cannot import RectangleBuilder

Comment: All xxBuilders (with xx instanceof Node) were removed (after fx8, I think - don't nail me on the exact version :)

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.